# Android random sensor values reported

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to analyze a bunch of Android sensor data from a Galaxy Nexus and im running into some weird patterns. For instance I am getting repeated values for 8 for the Magnetic Field sensors and random values of 255 for the Screen orientation sensor. These values dont seem to have any special significance in the documentation I read, yet they pop up repeatedly. Anyone have any idea why?

I included a sample of the sensor data output in case anyone wants it, 0 means no data returned in the listening time period (1 minute). Each row is 5 minutes different:

```
MPU6500 Acceleration Sensor AK09911C Magnetic field Sensor  AK09911C Magnetic Sensor UnCalibrated   MPU6500 Gyroscope Sensor    MPU6500 Uncalibrated Gyroscope Sensor   Barometer Sensor    TMG399X Proximity Sensor    TMG399X RGB Sensor  MPL Rotation Vector MPL Game Rotation Vector    SAMSUNG Step Detector Sensor    SAMSUNG Step Counter Sensor SAMSUNG Significant Motion Sensor   MAX86900    Screen Orientation Sensor   HRM Sensor  Orientation Sensor  Gravity Sensor  Linear Acceleration Sensor
-0.7918822  -1.44   8   -0.0010652645   0   0   0.027657    -0.00831    107.56043   0   0   255 0   0   -0.79049826 0.005798638 344.4021    -0.7916513  0.012937188
-1.6178818  18.66   -1.14   8   8   0   0.028444    -0.008315   0   0   0   255 0   0   -1.6365771  0.04024315  110.17886   -1.6392937  0.029791594
-1.638831   8   8   -2.66E-04   0   0.047552    -0.03045    0   0   0   255 0   0   0   -1.6823589  0.04951334  352.47757   -1.6795416  0.03173232
-1.6753427  -1.08   8   -0.0026631611   0   0.048844    -0.030235   0   1   0   255 0   0   0   -1.7105712  0.07293725  103.25511   -1.7080178  0.043449044
-1.721431   8   8   0.0013315806    0.0013315806    0.044273    -0.03007    0   0   0   255 0   0   0   -1.7184123  0.013740659 358.64462   -1.7213204  0.008867621
-1.7154455  18.72   -1.08   8   0.046393    -0.030042   0   0   0   255 0   0   0   0   -1.7471539  0.020335913 97.08981    -1.7468109  0.036153793
-1.8076223  -1.08   8   -0.0034621095   -0.0034621095   0   0.032184    -0.052209   0   0   0   255 0   0   -1.8572613  0.07178533  9.031282    -1.849128   0.043301344
-1.7962499  -1.08   8   8   -0.051598   -0.050319   1   0   0   255 0   0   0   0   -1.8097965  0.018933535 98.16796    -1.8121501  0.0069220066
-1.7830818  14.4    8   8   0   0   0.031865    -0.051793   0   0   0   0   0   255 -1.8501818  0.051537752 6.3113422   -1.8480959  0.033290982
-1.8968062  -1.02   8   8   0   0.035205    -0.051669   0   0   0   0   255 0   0   -1.9285302  0.06584132  9.900935    -1.9213988  0.02040255
-1.846528   15.06   8   8   0   0   0   88.72001    -0.0386 -1.8738624  255 0   0   0   -1.8782147  0.009540319 13.564674   -1.8787019  0.023794174
-1.2557588  18.6    8   8   0.002130529 -0.056822   -0.059393   0   0   255 0   0   1   0   -1.2829624  0.013437033 99.33356    -1.2816399  0.024684072
-1.2449849  18.6    8   0.014114754 0   0   0   85.962204   0.003289    -0.057907   -1.2985611  0   0   255 -1.2931483  0.042776465 14.364091   -1.2938662  0.037508845
-1.2443863  18.54   -1.26   8   8   0   0   -0.054567   -0.056251   2.5835018   0   0   255 0   -1.2474166  -0.011933446    93.84088    -1.2518827  -0.0062702894
-1.1426327  18.72   8   8   0   -0.052494   -0.056559   1   0   0   255 0   0   0   -1.1527904  0.017340302 6.746513    -1.1546664  0.01502645
-1.1492168  18.6    8   8   0.002396845 0   -0.048156   -0.04867    0   0   255 0   0   0   -1.1757433  0.03131497  99.13985    -1.1777196  0.019524574
-1.4927847  8   -2.66E-04   0   0   0.031505    -0.028662   0   0   255 0   0   1   0   -1.5062454  0.024833083 7.337884    -1.5073864  0.029565454
-1.5041572  18.78   0.005060006 8   8   0   0   -0.023542   -0.027803   5.926271    0   0   255 0   -1.5276097  0.030635118 91.725334   -1.527528   0.038933158
-1.5143325  -1.08   8   8   5.33E-04    0   0   0   0   -0.027872   0.04729855  85.258766   -1.529908   0   255 -1.5293596  0.009041548 -1.5280322  0.033451796
-1.4993688  14.52   8   8   0   -0.023884   -0.026326   0   0   255 0   0   0   0   -1.5211747  0.03198123  93.13916    -1.526189   0.013652086
-0.9816227  18.48   -1.32   8   8   0   0   0   -0.020971   -0.0265 -1.526189   0.5559387   7.78904 255 -1.0139774  0.030559063 85.279945   -1.0111967  0.031968236
-0.9756372  18.6    -1.2    8   8   0   0   -0.006156   -0.011322   0   0   255 0   1   -0.9895226  -0.0034725666   11.263685   -0.9939272  0.0069175363
-0.9923966  18.54   8   8   -0.0037284256   0   -0.010102   -0.010804   0   0   0   0   255 0   -1.011731   0.015144587 95.325294   -1.0129408  0.02712822
-0.7445967  0.12    8   8   0   -0.007972   -0.010841   0   0   255 0   0   0   0   -0.76289475 0.030269027 99.85943    -0.7639039  0.028285444
-0.18794483 19.62   -0.18   8   0   0   0.029863    0.031101    0   0   255 0   0   0   -0.19251534 0.0069647133    22.254642   -0.19720303 0.021827757
```

Answer (score 0):

With my Samsung Galaxy S5 (G900I), the screen orientation sensor returns the device's orientation in the range [0, 3] (inclusive) when the device's orientation is known. It returns 255 when the orientation is indeterminate.

For example, if the device is flat on its front or back, the sensor reports 255. Similarly, if the device is half-way between two orientations (portrait and landscape), the sensor reports 255.

This is all based on my own observation rather than documentation, since the screen orientation sensor doesn't seem to be standard. (I don't recall seeing any reference to this sensor in the Android developer documentation, and the SDK also doesn't seem to have a reference to it.)